# dont allow user to go back after login in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

How can we disable browser back button so that user can't go back? In my case there are two application running, After user successfully login I am checking the user type.If condition is true then I am redirecting user to another application in same tab by below code. If my condition goes false then he will be there only in APP-1.

```js
if(scope === "admin"){
  // open APP-2
  window.open({APP2_URL}, "_self");
}else{
  //continue on APP-1
  history.push('/');
}
```

So above code working as expected but the problem here I am facing is after user redirect to APP-2 he is able to click on back button and he is again going back to login page. So I am thinking to disable browser back button after he comes on APP-2. Is there any way to achieve this in reactjs?

Any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To don't allow user to go back on previous page use below code in your APP-2 landing page.

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
   window.onpopstate = function (event) {
       history.go(1);
   }
```

After writing this code user won't go to previous page, He will be there on current page. Try this and do let me know if its working or not.